# How can I invoke the name of a file associated with a batch process?

Tags: unix, pandoc

I'm trying to batch process a folder full of text files with pandoc, and I'd like to maintain the current filenames. How do I call the filename as a variable in the output? For example, I want to write a command like this:

```
pandoc -s notes/*.txt -o rtf/$1.rtf
```

Where $1 represents the filename grabbed with the `*` character.

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I don't quite know the right language to search for it properly.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
for file in notes/*txt 
do 
file_base_name=$(basename "${file}" | cut -d'.' -f1)
pandoc -s "$file" -o rtf/${file_base_name}.rtf
done
```